# Couldn't find Model without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there are many solutions for similar questions already but none of them seem to work for me.

I am trying to call a method **cancel_quote** from a controller **admin_reports**. This method updates the status of the particular row to number "8".

**cancel_quote** method in **admin_reports_controller**

```
def trip_report
 #####
 ####
end
def cancel_quote
    @ride_later_request = RideLaterRequest.find(params[:id])
    if @ride_later_request
      @ride_later_request.update(status: 8)
    end
    redirect_to trip_report_path
end
```

**trip_report.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to "Cancel", {:controller => :admin_reports, :action => 'cancel_quote'}, :method => :get %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :admin_reports do
    collection do
      get :cancel_quote
    end
  end
```

I followed some other solution and created a `@ride_later_request` object in view file itself and tried iterating over it and then fetching id from that object. That gave error too. Can somebody please tell me how do I get this done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well First thing 
Your route it should be member like

```
member do
  get :cancel_quote
end
```

As it specific to one object it better to have route with member.

then it will receive id as params, then run

```
rake routes | grep cancel_quote
```

copy that path and use it in your button path

```
<%= button_to "Cancel", cancel_quote_admin_report_path(current_id)%>
```

Try it directly first check if you are able to do it or not then pass the current id

```
<%= button_to "Cancel", cancel_quote_admin_report_path(8)%>
```

OR

you can pass id to your collection method too, which is not correct way but here it is.

```
<%= button_to "Cancel", cancel_quote_admin_reports_path(id: current_id)%>
```

Comment: This seems to be working. But for checking purpose I explicitly gave the id number myself like `cancel_quote_admin_report_path(1)`. It successfully updated the status of the object with id 1 to `status: 8`. But how am I supposed to pass the id dynamically there ?

Comment: In your form you must be getting params[:id] or id of `RideLaterRequest` which you want to update. apply debugger and check that.

Comment: After giving params[:id] says `:id=Nil` missing required keys

Comment: do you hv  object of `RideLaterRequest` in your form? or what do u have in your `trip_report` form

Comment: Yes I do. But that object is from another method. In another method I have `@rfq=RideLaterRequest.all` and in the same form I am using it for other purpose.

Comment: and you have cancel button in loop?  means that cancel request would be for each record of `RideLaterRequest` right? then you can just pass that iterating object instead of `1` directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160027/discussion-between-teju-c-and-user3576036).